# How to change RDS Security Group using boto3?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I am restoring *(=creating a new instance)* an RDS MySQL Snapshot using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot). Unfortunately the Security Group does not get copied over instead it gets assigned the *default* Security Group which is has no limitations on incoming traffic.

Looking at the source RDS instance I can see the correct Security Group (sg-a247eec5) attached to the RDS instance. This Security Group is visible under *EC2 - Security Groups* **and** *VPC - Security Groups* but not under *RDS - Security Groups*.

I am using [restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot) but I can't see where I would attach that Security Group to the new instance.

*I can easily attach the correct Security Group by using the AWS UI (modifying my RDS Instance).*

There is [modify_instance_attribute](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_instance_attribute) on the EC2 client which can change Security Groups, but it requires an **InstanceId** which I don't get from my RDS instance. The only thing I can find is **DBInstanceIdentifier**.

*Trying to set the correct IAM permissions confuses me too. I have an RDS ARN: arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-2:<account_id>:db:<db_instance_name> but ModifyInstanceAttribute is listed under Amazon EC2. Selecting both in the policy editor gives me an error saying the ARN is invalid (which makes sense).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use **restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot** api, the default behavior is to apply `default security group` and `default parameter group`. The same is documented in [RDS API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot.html).

> The target database is created from the source database restore point
>   with the most of original configuration with the default security
>   group and the default DB parameter group.

The workaround is to use **modify_db_instance** api once the restore is complete.
*DBInstanceIdentifier is to an RDS instance, what an InstanceId is to an EC2 instance*.

Pass the same ***DBInstanceIdentifier*** which you used above, as an input to this api.

```
response = client.modify_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='string',
    DBSecurityGroups=[
        'string',
    ], /* If you are using ec2 security groups then remove this and use VpcSecurityGroupIds. */

    VpcSecurityGroupIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    DBParameterGroupName='string',
    ApplyImmediately=True,

)
```

I believe you need to change both the security-group as well as parameter-group(unless you are fine with the default one). If you are changing the parameter-group, then you need to reboot the db instance as well for the settings to take effect.

```
response = client.reboot_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='string',
)
```

Also, you need the role performing the above db operations to have the below policy permissions.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1507879517000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:ModifyDBInstance",
                "rds:RebootDBInstance",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*:XXXXXXXXXX:db:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `rds:CreateDBInstance` wasn't needed. Apart from that, this is just a perfect answer. Thanks heaps!